# What are the other level stars?

Tags: pyramids

In Pyramids for the 3DS, you can apparently get three stars after completing a level. The one with the symbol of the open door appears to be given if you just complete a level, but the two other ones have me stumped. One is a bag of coins, and the other one is a bag of coins with a timer.

I assume the latter one has something to do with completing the level quickly, but what about the bag of coins star? It might have something to do with collecting treasure or coins in a level, but then again, some of the early levels don't seem to have treasure in them - so how would I get that star?

Am I right in my assumptions? If so, how do I get these stars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a [review of the game](http://3dsware.nintendolife.com/reviews/2011/10/pyramids_3dsware):

> Each stage has three stars available: one star for simply reaching the goal, two stars for reaching the goal and collecting all treasure items, and three stars for achieving both of these tasks within a stringent time limit.

It's possible that you'll get both the time and time+treasure star if you complete a level under the time limit that contains no treasure, but you might want to pick an easy one and see if that's the case.

You might also have to destroy blocks, like in [this video](http://www.elecplay.com/all/spotlight/pyramids-3ds-review-video/), in order to uncover treasures that have been hidden.

Comment: Hm. That doesn't explain why in some levels (like the first one) there doesn't appear to be any treasure (unless I am missing something, I also am not sure if I can "dig out" blocks from underneath myself or not) you don't seem to get the star.

Comment: Skip to about 31 seconds in the video review [here](http://www.elecplay.com/all/spotlight/pyramids-3ds-review-video/), where it looks like the guy is doing just that to uncover some hidden treasures.

Comment: Awesome. That is incredibly helpful.